# Weka Prediction margin using Java API

Tags: java, weka

Hellow everyone,
I'm using Weka Java API for predictions. I was able to get the expected and actual behavior from the java code. But now what i wanted is to get the 'prediction margin' information from final results. From GUI, i can manage, but i wanted is a Java solution. appreciate if any one can help.What i wanted to get is the below highlighted information using java.
[image]

Below code shows the code i'm using as of now to predict actual/predicted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < testDataSet.numInstances(); i++) {
        double actualClass = testDataSet.instance(i).classValue();
        String actual = testDataSet.classAttribute().value((int) actualClass);
        
        Instance newInst = testDataSet.instance(i);
        double preJ48 = tree.classifyInstance(newInst);

                  String predictionString = testDataSet.classAttribute().value((int) preJ48);
        System.out.println("Actual : " + actual + "   Prediction : " + predictionString);
    }
```

############################# Solution i found as below ##########

```
 J48 tree = new J48();
    tree.buildClassifier(trainDataSet);
    double a = eval.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(tree, testDataSet.instance(0));

    eval.evaluateModel(tree, testDataSet, plainText);
 

    for (String line : predsBuffer.toString().split("\n")) {
        String[] linesplit = line.split("\\s+");

        // If there's an error(error flag "+"), the length of linesplit is 6, otherwise 5

        System.out.println("linesplit "+linesplit.length);
        int id;
        String expectedValue, classification;
        double probability;

        if (line.contains("+")) {
          
            probability = Double.parseDouble(linesplit[5]);
            System.out.println("Its Minus "+probability);
        } else {
           
            probability = Double.parseDouble(linesplit[4]);
            System.out.println("Its Plus "+probability);
        }
    }
```

Comment: any expert idea pls.

Comment: can anyone direct a person or place at least pls ?

Answer (score 0):

The *prediction margin* that you are referring to gets generated by the [weka.gui.explorer.ClassifierErrorsPlotInstances](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/eebdd35e31ec76315bdca176974a4007beae0673/weka/src/main/java/weka/gui/explorer/ClassifierErrorsPlotInstances.java) class. Check the variables `probActual` and `probNext` in its [process](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/eebdd35e31ec76315bdca176974a4007beae0673/weka/src/main/java/weka/gui/explorer/ClassifierErrorsPlotInstances.java#L325) method.

This margin is simply the difference between the probability for the actual class label and the highest probability of the label that isn't the actual class label.

You can use the `distributionForInstance` method of your classifier to obtain the class distribution array and then determine these two probabilities to calculate the margin for the prediction.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I found and alternative too. Let me check it and reply here. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Please post your alternative here as well.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4698227/fracpete I've added the solution I found. Didn't try your one yet. Thanks again for the reply.